# Taking 'salt tablets' when running longer distances

Tags: nutrition, long-distance-running, marathon

I'm running a marathon in March (my 5th overall) and the last marathon I suffered with severe cramp after 23 miles. I've been advised to take 'salt tablets' by another runner.

I've done some research into salt tablets however have been met with a lot of 'sales' talk and ambiguous information.

My Questions: Are there any scientific benefits to taking salt tablets when running longer distances?

Comment: I would caution you on making any changes close to a race without having tried it in your training runs first.

Comment: Cramping is (mostly) attributed to going too hard for either weather conditions or fitness. The links between salt supplementation and cramping are still in the realm of "bro science". Some people swear by them and have great results, others see no effect, and studies have not proven anything one way or another.

Comment: Interesting @JohnP. Seems like there is a lot of debate about this and not a huge amount of fact. I'll give them a go and see what effect (if any) they have. Thanks!

Comment: @KristianBright - I would echo rrirower's suggestion. Don't do anything new on race day, and experiment during your workouts. Also pay attention to fluid intake, one of the biggest things I've seen in triathletes is they add salt, forget to drink more and end up in worse shape from stomach ills.

Comment: Not a marathon runner but I feel like one sometimes after a long day of refereeing soccer matches.  My remedy for incipient cramps is a shot of mustard.  I always carry a couple of packets in my pocket. Doubt if there is any science and it may very well be a placebo but it usually works for me.

Comment: It might have nothing to do with sodium loss, it could be a fatigue cramp. As the race progresses, you get tired, your form starts to go south, other muscles groups try to cover, and BAM; your muscles put the break on.

Answer (score -1):

The main reason behind taking salt is because sodium helps regulate the body's fluid levels.
If you run for longer periods of time and sweat a lot, you will also lose sodium(Your sweat tastes salty if it has ever dripped into your mouth).

The loss of salt is also connected to other running problems, like cramping.
Basically if your body runs low on sodium, you are in danger of getting over hydrated, which is not good.

I guess you should talk with some doctor about it, because it highly depends on you. Are you a heavy sweater? How long do you run? How old are you? How much water do you drink? etc. etc.
These are questions that i sadly can not answer and contacting an expert will give you a more detailed answer, on how much salt you should consume. Because too much could be even worse, than lacking it.

I'am pretty sure tho, that regular salt will do just as well, and the need for tablets is just not there. But i guess they are effective, if you want to ingest them mid run.

At the end of the day, you must try. If it works for you good, if it doesn't, don't do it.

Comment: The connection between electrolytes and cramping is still unproven. Studies of long distance triathletes have shown no difference in serum sodium levels with or without supplementation.

Comment: The fact is that when you sweat, you lose sodium. I even googeled an article for you
http://www.runnersworld.com/nutrition-runners/pass-salt?page=single and it seems to help people, so how can you argue?

Comment: Actually, you lose much more than just sodium. But, this has not been proven in studies to cause cramping. As of this point, what causes cramps is still basically an unknown. bjsm.bmj.com/content/40/3/255.short

Comment: http://www.fleetfeettucson.com/blogs/ask-a-nuritionist/can-a-lack-of-salt-cause-muscle-cramps
I am now just googeling everything at this point...
More
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramp

Comment: I'll take a scientific study over a generic blog that can't even get nutritionist spelled right, thanks.

Comment: And I know there are tons of people out there that absolutely believe that electrolyte imbalances cause cramps, and salt supplementation is the answer, but none of that has been proven yet. It's still all in the realm of "it *may* help".

Comment: Even if it is placebo(i do not see how), it is still better than nothing and being cramped up on a road.No?

Comment: At the end of the day, i am just trying to help someone. I get my knowledge from scientific articles as well, but most of the times, there aren't any on that specific subject, so i turn to wikipedia and bodybuilding articles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20839/discussion-between-johnp-and-s3v3ns).